# Solving difference equation with integration

Tags: integration, ordinary-differential-equations, numerical-methods

There is following problem:

$$C_{(q)}\frac{\partial v}{\partial t}= i_{(t)}$$

a differential equation for current through capacitor, where $i_{(t)}$ denotes a rest of the circuit including *serial* and *parallel* *resistance* (and other non-linear components, not changing the nature of the problem). Now, discretizing the problem with 1st order method:

$$\frac{v_{[k+1]} - v_{[k]}}{\Delta t} = \frac{1}{C_{(q)}}*i_{(k)}$$

As the the notation $C_{(q)}$ shows, the $C$ is a function of free parameter $q$, such that $C_{(q)} = 0$ for $q_0$. This poses an immediate question, on how to solve  case for $q_{0}$ when $\frac{1}{C_{(q_0)}} \to\infty$.

From physical point of view, the $C=0$ is valid case (e.g. the value of C is lowered/neglected, so the circuit behaves statically), but solution based on differentiation of $v$ fails, because the $C_{(q_0)}$ is in denominator.

---

*QUESTIONs*

1. Can the problem be solved by integration of $i$, instead by derivation of $v$ ?
2. Does (any) numerical integration method, have the same/similar properties in terms of errors, as the Runge-Kutta methods (max error is kept within known limits, also higher order method, lower error).

---

P.S. The problem is extremely simplified, the term $i(t)$ is complex function for whole circuit. Please dont post analytical methods for solving differential equations !

---

EDIT: More info/insight view into the problem.

The following holds and should be taken into consideration ([source](https://www.mathworks.com/help/physmod/elec/ref/variablecapacitor.html)):

$$\frac{\partial C_{(q)}}{\partial t}v + C_{(q)}\frac{\partial v}{\partial t}= i_{(t)}$$

Comment: There's too much physics to still be interjected here to explain what math to follow; for example in the small capacitance limit, it is no longer sensical to neglect resistance.

Comment: @Ian The resistance is not neglected, the term $i_{(t)}$ denotes the rest of the circuit (with serial and parallel resistance)

Comment: Then you cannot simply roll that all into one term like this in the situation where the capacitance is going to zero.

Comment: @Ian I have edited the question to not cause misunderstanding about missing resistance. But the specific components are not important from numerical point of view (except the serial resistance, that is mentioned now). Do you have any other suggestion ?

Comment: Essentially the infinitesimal capacitance/inductance limit (with all linear components) is the infinitesimal memory limit, that is the system instantaneously relaxes to its steady state given any perturbation. To leading order this doesn't involve ODE integration at all, it is just an algebraic equation at each time. Of course in reality there is still fine time scale ODE integration for relaxation processes, due to small but nonzero capacitance/inductance. Are you trying to devise a method for resolving the internals of these fine scale events?

Comment: @Ian Thanks, I have edited the question again. The $q$ actually varies, the $C_{(q)}$ is not constant, it slowly changes to $C=0$ and then $C>0$ repeatedly.

Comment: The fact that the dynamics of $C$ are slow does not allow you to decouple them from the remainder of the circuit in the vicinity of a zero of $C$. You must be more careful about time scale separation in the vicinity of singularities.

Comment: @Ian Can you point me to a book/more information ?

Comment: @Ian Please can you have a look at the question, whether the problem is stated in a clear manner ? If, not , may I ask for suggestion to improve it ?